# Access a property in an array on an object with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to access some information of a blog with Typescript. I can't figure out how to get access to the title item since it is in an array.

```
    export default function Post({list}: Props) {
console.log(" ~ file: post.tsx ~ line 13 ~ Post ~ getBlog", list)
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>{list?.listBlogs?.items?.title}</h1>
    <img src={list?.getBlog?.coverImage}></img>
    <p>{list?.getBlog?.content}</p>

    <p>A whole paragraph</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Also attaching the snippet showing the error I am getting on title. [image]

Comment: So you have multiple blogs, each with its own title. Which blog do you want to get the title from?

Comment: So this is using graphql and listBlogs is supposed to return ALL blogs. I know that I am supposed to somehow do something along the lines of list.listBlogs.items.map() => {

}

but I am not sure how to map it I guess

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up learning that you can map it out like so:

```
    export default function Post({blog}: Props) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
    {blog?.listBlogs?.items?.map((blogTitle) => {
      return (
        <div className="allBlogs">
            <img src={blogTitle?.coverImage}></img>
            <h1>Title: {blogTitle?.title}</h1>
            <p>{blogTitle?.content}</p>
        </div>
    )
    })}
    </div>
  )
}
```